# Inheritance method, the derived method invokes not the base

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have class A and class B, for instance this is the code

```
class A{
void show(){.....}}

class B:public A{
void show(){....}}

void main()
{ int arr[2];
arr[0]=new A();
arr[1]=new B();
arr[1]->show();
}
```

in this situation I want the show of class B to action, but no matters what I did it always go to ths 'show' of the parent..

what can I do?

Comment: Are you sure `arr` has type `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make it a `virtual` method in the base class, also the array should be `A*` in your case not `int`. Then these two point will solve your problem:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void show() {}
  //^^^^^^^
};

struct B : public A
{
    void show() {}
    /* virtual void show() override {} */
};

int main()
{
    A *arr[2];
    arr[0] = new A;
    arr[1] = new B;

    arr[1]->show();
}
```

---

Last word, avoid bare pointers, you can use smart pointers such as `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void show() {};
};

struct B : public A
{
    void show() {}
    /* virtual void show() override {} */
};

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<A> arr[2];

    arr[0].reset(new A);
    arr[1].reset(new B);

    arr[1]->show();
}
```

Comment: You'll want to mark B's show() method as virtual and override as well.

Comment: @MikeWoolf: Do you mean I should write `virtual` for `B::show` too? It's unnecessary per §10.3/1 in standard and you can omit it. BTW, it's good practice to repeat it over derived classes and I've put it in the answer as a comment.